# Parallel vectors in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I need some help with the use of parallel vectors. What I want to do is have 2 vectors, 1 containing the alphabet, and the other containing the alphabet the other way around. When someone types in a word, it prints out the word using the inverted alphabet.

This is what I've done up until now and I'm not too sure if I'm on the right track or not:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <ctype.h>

using namespace std;

void search(char alfab[], char cripto[], int code){
    cout << "Introduce your message: " << endl;
    cin >> code;

    for(int i = 0; i < code; i++)
    {
        if(code == 0){
            cout << "Your code is:" << cripto[i] << endl;
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    char alfab[26] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};
    char cripto[26] = {'z','y','x','w','v','u','t','s','r','q','p','o','n','m','l','k','j','i','h','g','f','e','d','c','b','a'};
    char code;
}
```

Comment: This is not C to start with...

Comment: Are you trying to write C or C++ code? The title and tags say C but your code is C++.

Comment: `char code`, `int code`, `cin >> code` (for a parameter passed by value to the function)... Everything looks wrong...

Comment: Please review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). "Does it look right?" is not a good question for Stackoverflow as it is too unfocused. Try to ask about a specific error or problem.

Comment: Using a `std::map` could help

Comment: I second using a `map` instead of two `vector`s.

Comment: I agree with the above posters that you should use `std::map`, but if you really are constrained to using vectors, you will want to use [`std::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find).  Also, this can be done efficiently without any containers at all if you know how ASCII works! (Hint: 'a' == 97)

Comment: What about using some math instead?  `encripted = (25 - (original_char - 'a')) + 'a';`  No need for arrays.

Comment: You appear not to need help with dealing with arrays but with coding C/C++ in general. I suggest you start over with the basics and would suggest watching some C/C++ tutorial videos on youtube.

Answer (score 2):

Think about how you would do this by hand.  Then try to translate those steps to code.

```
Get user input
for each letter:
   decide which letter of your reversed alphabet it is
   write that new letter down in the same position as the original
output new string
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something more like this instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

static const char alfab[26] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};
static const char cripto[26] = {'z','y','x','w','v','u','t','s','r','q','p','o','n','m','l','k','j','i','h','g','f','e','d','c','b','a'};

std::string invert(const std::string &word){
    std::string inverted = word;
    for(std::string::size_type i = 0; i < inverted.size(); ++i)
    {
        char ch = inverted[i];
        for(int j = 0; j < 26; ++j)
        {
            if (alfab[j] == ch)
            {
                inverted[i] = cripto[j];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return inverted;
}

int main(){
    std::string word;

    std::cout << "Enter a word: " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> word;

    std::cout << "Your code is: " << invert(word) << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using one array:

```
std::string invert(const std::string& original)
{
    static const char cripto[26] = 
    { 
        'z','y','x','w',
        'v','u','t','s','r',
        'q','p','o','n','m',
        'l','k','j','i','h',
        'g','f','e','d','c',
        'b','a'
    };
    const size_t length = original.length();
    std::string inverted_text;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < length)
    {
       char c = original[i];
       inverted_text += cripto[c - 'a'];
    }
    return inverted_text;
}
```

**Edit 1:  Using some math**
You could simplify the encryption (inversion) by using some math.

```
std::string invert(const std::string& original)
{
    const size_t length = original.length();
    std::string inverted_text;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < length)
    {
       char c = original[i];
       inverted_text += (25 - (c - 'a')) + 'a';
    }
    return inverted_text;
}
```

**Using transform**
You could use `std::transform`:

```
char invert_char(char c)
{
    return (25 - (c - 'a')) + 'a':
}

//...
std::transform(original_word.begin(), original_word.end(),
               original_word.begin(), invert_char);
```